# VSTi MIDI effect

Tags: midi, vst, vsti

I know it's possible to write a VSTi that's an audio effect. But, I was wondering, is it possible to make one that's a *MIDI* effect? E.g. a VST that catches MIDI notes before they go to the instrument and edits their pitch, velocity, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, Cubase has many of them built-in -  https://steinberg.help/cubase_plugin_reference/v9/en/plug_ref/topics/midi_effects_r.html There is, however, no real SDK for it.

VST3 drops a lot of the support for midi that VST2 had.
https://forums.steinberg.net/t/creating-a-midi-effect/201569
https://forums.steinberg.net/t/vst3-and-midi-cc-pitfall/201879?page=3